# Set default username and password for everything using SVN on client

Tags: caching, svn, version-control, credentials

I have a test PC that carries out automated parsing checks against numerous SVN repos. The client uses simple username/password authentication. The script typically goes like:

1. Cleanup working copy via `svn cleanup`, and delete all non-versioned files.
2. Revert and local changes via `svn revert -R *`
3. Update the local working copies via `svn up * --username user1 --password testpass`
4. Run the parser checkers, compile the occasional project.

Some of the parsing tools used carry out SVN operations (ie: request the output of `svn info`, `svn diff`, and `svn log`) to generate additional metrics. If an `auth` entry for the local user account doesn't already have a matching entry in `~localuser/.subversion/auth/svn.simple`, then the operation will fail.

Every time a developer adds a new `svn external` to the repo, this causes the script to fail. Is it possible to configure SVN to just always use the same username and password by default for all new repos/externs it encounters, and to cache the credentials?

Comment: Aways have the same user/pass for all URLs and use hardcoded `--username ... --password ...` in `svn up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use always `--username ... --password ...` in update **and** all repositories are on enumerated amount of hosts, you can pre-fill `.subversion/auth/svn.simple` on build-server with all credentials **for realms**: every records have **realm** (URL of host) as key and stored for realm credentials used by default for all repositories in realm (f.e. I have more than 1 repo for `svn:realmstring
V 54
<http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088> VisualSVN Server` but just one credentials-record and can use any repository, there *which hat* is needed... yes, more than single user for real will be troublesome - I can get&save additional credentials, but SVN will not be able to select proper user)